# Bash script that removes C source comments

Tags: bash

I need to write a bash script which copies all `.c` files from a directory `$2` to another directory `$1`, but without comments.

I only have to remove comments that begin with `//`, might have tabs/spaces before the comment, but not letters.

Also, I need to do it with only a few executed lines (no workaround using `;`). Does anyone has an idea?

For now I have the `.c` files stored in an array which I need to iterate through:

```
file_list=()
while IFS= read -d $'\0' -r file
do
    file_list=("${file_list[@]}" "$file")
done < <(find "$2" -maxdepth 1 -name '*.c' -print0)
```

Thanks

Comment: `awk '!/^[[:space:]]*\/\//' file` ?

Comment: So, you don't need to catch comments like this one: `++i;  // increment i`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass all your files through a sed command like this:

```
sed -i "s#[[:space:]]*//.*##g" filepath
```

If you want to reserve comments which have codes before it (like `i++;//comment`), then:

```
sed -i "/^[[:space:]]*\/\/.*/d" filepath
```